# Check boolean from another php script

Tags: php

I want to check if a boolean is true or false from antoher phpscript.
Like if I have a boolean like this in one php script:

```
$signedin = false;
```

then I want to check if it is false or true by another php script in another file.
 I hope someone can help me! :)

Thanks!

Comment: Do a little research on PHP sessions.  That's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For checking the status of a signed in user, you'll generally want to use sessions, like

```
<?php 
session_start();
// whatever code ...
$_SESSION['signedIn'] = true;
```

Then on any script, you'd just check that variable:

```
<?php
session_start(); 
$signedIn = $_SESSION['signedIn'];
```

To literally answer your question though, here:

scriptA.php

```
function checkSignedIn(){
    return ($signedIn === true);
}
```

scriptB

```
include_once('scriptA.php');
$signedIn = checkSignedIn();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use sessions: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php